# Js not loading after routing in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I am building an Angular4 WebApp using an external HTML template for my components. The template needs to run some scripts to load correctly the page. 
If I include script tags in my index.html the page loads fine the first time but when I route to another page scripts are not reloaded for the component template and the page remains blank.
Is there another way to load scripts and solve this issue?
Please Help.

here are my files. when application loads it works fine but when i route to some other page the js links in index.html wont load.
My app.component.html file only have

[this is my app.module file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTz07.png)

[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFqQB.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please add some of your code here to understand what exactly you have done? It's difficult to help without seeing what you have done so far.

Comment: Hey @ankitsuthar I've added some pictures of my program please have a look. Thank you.

Comment: Did you find any solution about this problem?

Comment: Same here, waiting for answer.